# ViewPager + Seekbar : when trying to slide seekbar, viewPager changes fragment instead

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, seekbar

i have a viewPager with three fragments. the middle (second) fragment has a seekBar implemented in it. When i am trying to slide the seek bar, the viewPager changes the fragment instead.

There was one other post where the user had a similar problem and offered a solution, but that solution completely disengages the swipe function from the viewPager.

How do i keep both swipe functions, but focus the seekbar, when the seekbar view is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured the answer. If someone is still stuck with the question.
Create a custom class of SwipeRefreshlayout and add to layout.

```
    public class CustomSwipeRefresh extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private float mPrevX;
    private boolean isDisabled;

    public CustomSwipeRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    public void disableInterceptTouchEvent(boolean isDisabled) {
        this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(isDisabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPrevX = MotionEvent.obtain(event).getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (isDisabled) {
                    return false;
                }
                float eventX = event.getX();
                float xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - mPrevX);
                if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                    return false;
                }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Then on your fragment class with seekbar, just add the code

```
mswiperefresh.disableInterceptTouchEvent(boolean);
```

to enable and disable swipe focus.

```
 @Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
     mswiperefresh.disableInterceptTouchEvent(true);
      }

 @Override
     public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          mswiperefresh.disableInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }
```